# How to fix a broken relay that's still clicking?

Tags: relay, output, damage

Last week, one of my cooking plates was not working any more.

I was able to track the problem down to the cooking plate relay (Finder relay type 45.61, 14Vdc, 16A, 250Vac).

This relay still makes clicking noise when powering the coil, but the output (NO) does not short. Unfortunately, this relay can not be purchased any more.

My questions:
1.) What might have happened to the NO contacts of the relay? Thin oxide layer?
2.) Is there any chance to repair this relay, e.g. by stressing it with 1K on/off cycles or heating it up to e.g. 120°C?

Thanks for your thoughts on this.

Edit1: I found a similar series datasheet
https://cdn-reichelt.de/documents/datenblatt/C300/FIN_45_DB_DE.pdf

The pinout looks like this, so maybe the Type 45.71 might fit.
[image]

Comment: How does the capsule look? Easy to carefully pry open and take a look inside? I’ve brushed off some automotive relay contact points in a pinch with acceptable results. What does the pinout look like? The relay may be out of production but there could be others which fits.

Comment: Most likely you can find an equivalent relay that will fit the PCB exactly, however 14V is not a common coil voltage. It’s possible a 12V relay and series resistor could be substituted. Most likely the contacts are worn out.

Comment: @winny: After finding the 45.71 as possible replacement, I don't want to repair the broken one anymore. But I will definitely ook inside once I have replaced it.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany: Thanks. The replacement has 12V, but is rated 1.2 U_nom, so 14.4V max. voltage. Assuming that the driver voltage has 3% tolerance (? to be checked), it could work without an additional resistor. (BTW: What do you mean by "the contacts are worn out?")

Comment: FYI, I ordered the 45.91.7.012. This is the only one that supports 1A at 220V. I will write an answer to this question after I changed the relais and disassembled the broken one.

Comment: @StefanWyss contacts get used up: when the relay closes, they get a mechanical shock, but much worse, when the relay opens, there's a bit of arcing while the contacts move away from each other. That flash burns through the contact material (slowly, because relays are made with alloys that are quite resistant to that).

Comment: although it's good to have an exact coil voltage match, a 12V or 15V relay is probably going to work fine with 14V coil voltage. They are not as delicate as computer chips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I got the new relais and replaced the broken ones. All cooking plates are operational, and I can eat hot, tasty food again ;-)

I disassembled one of the broken relais and it turned out that there were multiple problems: The contacts were covered with "black stuff" and one contact was slightly bended, so when I powered the relais on, it was not able to close mechanically and electrically. I tried to clean the contacts with sand paper, but I was not able to get the relais working again.

To answer my own question: I assume there was no chance to repair this relais without opening it (by simply applying some current, heat or vibration). I was lucky to find a similar relais from the same manufacturer.

Here is a picture from the broken relais:
[image]